# Python: Unicode encoding different between Mac and Ubuntu

Tags: python, macos, ubuntu, unicode, tornado

While I am developing WAS server using tornado 3.2.2,

I confront some unicode problem after I changed system from Mac to Ubuntu.

Under Mac environment, it works fine.

However, with same DB(remote MySQL server), same source code, it show different

result under ubuntu.

The only thing different between these two are the operating machines(mac and ubuntu 14.04)

and the python version(mac: 2.7.8, ubuntu: 2.7.6)

Under **Mac**, it shows correct result like below

`"remark": "30\uc77c \uc774\uc6a9\uad8c"`

But under **ubuntu**, it appears like this

`"remark": "30? ???"`

I have been trying to do everything I find on the web for 2 days.

But I can't find why.

I have been tried every encode/decode ways I can do like below:

```
print(type(test_dict["remark"]))
print(test_dict["remark"].encode("utf-8").decode("euc-kr"))
print(test_dict["remark"].decode("utf-8").encode("euc-kr"))
print(test_dict["remark"].encode("euc-kr").decode("utf-8"))
print(test_dict["remark"].decode("euc-kr").encode("utf-8"))
print(unicode(test_dict["remark"], 'utf-8'))
encoding = chardet.detect(test_dict["remark"])
print(encoding)
print(test_dict["remark"].decode("unicode-escape"))
print(unicode(test_dict["remark"], "utf-8"))
print(unicode(test_dict["remark"], "utf-8").decode("utf-8").encode("utf-8"))
print(unicode(test_dict["remark"], "utf-8").encode("utf-8").decode("utf-8"))
for c in test_dict["remark"]:
    if c not in string.ascii_letters:
        print(" not ascii")
    else:
        print("ascii")
print(test_dict["remark"].decode(encoding["encoding"]).encode("utf-8"))
print(test_dict["remark"].encode("utf-8"))
print(test_dict["remark"].decode("utf-8").encode("euc-kr"))
print(unicode(test_dict["remark"].decode("utf-8").encode("utf-8")))
```

also tornado.escape method too.

But it work out still wrong.

the result is like below under **Ubuntu**:

```
<type 'str'>
30? ???
30? ???
30? ???
30? ???
30? ???
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
30? ???
30? ???
30? ???
30? ???
 not ascii
 not ascii
 not ascii
 not ascii
 not ascii
 not ascii
 not ascii
30? ???
30? ???
30? ???
30? ???
```

**changing locale setting to euc-kr is not allowed**

My locale setting is like below

**Mac**

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

**Ubuntu**

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

I found something weird while I am testing...

**under code, it appears different between two systems**

```
encoding = chardet.detect(test_dict["remark"])
```

Under **Mac**

```
{'confidence': 0.938125, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}
```

Under **Ubuntu**

```
{'confidence': 1.0, 'encoding': 'ascii'}
```

Anyone knows why this is happening?

Any idea or advice would be very thankful for me.

Thank you in advance

Comment: If you really are seeing those question marks there then the data is coming in broken.

Comment: I solved above problem. It wasn't any encoding problem.
The solution is how I connect to database.
I just added ?charset=utf8 in connecting to MySQL
In my case, I'm using SQLAlchemy to connect so I added it
It works fine Thanks, everyone

Answer (score 0):

If you were hoping for this Unicode Korean output:

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
>>> print u"30\uc77c \uc774\uc6a9\uad8c"
30일 이용권
```

then the only thing that I can think which is causing wrong output is that your terminal is not talking UTF-8.

But then again, if OS X was giving you "30\uc77c \uc774\uc6a9\uad8c" it doesn't seem to be doing much better (unless you are able to read two octet codepoints from the basic multilingual plane (which would be very impressive)).